# How to make repentance/tawbah for sins?

Tags: sin, tawba

I have read online and saw some videos that say that there are some conditions of seeking forgiveness from ALLAH (SWT) and having it accepted:

1. Admit you have commited that sin.
2. Regret having done the sin.
3. Seek forgiveness from Allah for commiting the sin.
4. Promise not to do the sin again.
5. Restore people’s rights or property if the sin involved wrongdoing towards others
6. Repent before the agony of death.

I want to know what do in the following example:
Imagine someone has done this:

- Drank alcohol 3 times.
- Commited zina 5 times.
- Listened to music 2 times.

How does the person repent in this example? Must that person repent

- 10 times for each sin.
- 1 time for having drunk alcohol, 1 time for zina and 1 time for music
- Repent only once for all the sins.

I am asking to know since many people including myself have done many many major sins that if we were to repent for each sin individually we would need to pray 50000 prayers everyday. Does anyone have a reference to answer my question? Thanks for your help.